# How do I create a helper with block?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, helper

I want to make a helper like the following.

```
def my_div some_options, &block
  # How do I print the result of the block?
end
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You should use [CaptureHelper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html).

```
def my_div(some_options, &block)
  # capture the value of the block a string
  content = capture(&block)
  # concat the value to the output
  concat(content)
end

<% my_div([]) do %>
  <p>The content</p>
<% end %>


def my_div(some_options, &block)
  # capture the value of the block a string
  # and returns it. You MUST use <%= in your view.
  capture(&block)
end

<%= my_div([]) do %>
  <p>The content</p>
<% end %>
```

Use capture + concat if you need to concat the output.
Use capture if you need to capture and then reuse the content. If your block doesn't explicitely use <%=, then you MUST call concat (preferred way).

This is an example of a method that hides the content if the user it not an admin.

```
def if_admin(options = {}, &block)
  if admin?
    concat content_tag(:div, capture(&block), options)
  end
end

<% if_admin(:style => "admin") do %>
<p>Super secret content.</p>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

so two things that are important:

- rails ignores anything that isn't a string in a `content_tag` (and `content_for`)
- you can't use `Array#join` (etc.) because it produces unsafe strings, you need to use `safe_join` and `content_tag` to have safe strings
- I didn't need either `capture` or `concat` in my case.

```rb
  def map_join(objects, &block)
    safe_join(objects.map(&block))
  end

  def list(objects, &block)
    if objects.none?
      content_tag(:p, "none")
    else
      content_tag(:ul, class: "disc") do
        map_join(objects) do |object|
          content_tag(:li) do
            block.call(object)
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

this can be used like this:

```
= list(@users) do |user|
  => render user
  = link_to "show", user
```

(this is slim but works fine with erb too)

Comment: The `safe_join` tip really saved me! Never knew this. Ended up concatenating with `+` instead, but really good to know.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.rubycentral.com/book/tut_containers.html

The yield statement will return the result of the block passed. So if you wanted to print (console?)

```
def my_div &block
  yield
end

my_div { puts "Something" }
```

Would output "Something"

But:
What is the idea of your method? Outputting a DIV?

Comment: weppos has a much better answer 8)

Comment: you can't use "puts" to output content in a template, this will just output to the standard output (e.g. in your rails server terminal logs)